# HBase : Failed to store data (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException)

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Unable to store data using table.put(p) method, Which is throwing an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException
```

Please check below for complete exception details:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family ColumnFamily1 
 does not exist in region hbasesample2,,1440880732948.e63f5e1b82327208a862a98b302b9c85. in table 'hbasesample2', {NAME => 'ColumnFamily1 ', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily10', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily2', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily3', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily4', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily5', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily6', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily7', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily8', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'ColumnFamily9', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:1896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
: 1 time, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1700(AsyncProcess.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.flush(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:1095)
    at Hbase.Hbase_Auto.main(Hbase_Auto.java:93)
```

Here is the code snippet :

```
p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(colfamily),Bytes.toBytes(column),Bytes.toBytes(temp));
table.put(p);
```

Please somebody who know about this help me out.

#### EDIT #1

I have pasted below the "description" of the table 'hbasesample2', the column family are same as the one which we find in that exception. Totally I have 10 column family for that table, as of now I have copy pasted some 4 family desc.

---

```
hbase(main):003:0> describe 'hbasesample2'
Table hbasesample2 is ENABLED                                                                                                                                           
hbasesample2                                                                                                                                                            
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                             
{NAME => 'ColumnFamily1 ', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', T
TL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}                                                       
{NAME => 'ColumnFamily10', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', T
TL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}                                                       
{NAME => 'ColumnFamily2', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TT
L => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}                                                        
{NAME => 'ColumnFamily3', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TT
L => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

Comment: the error is right there in the message:
NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family ColumnFamily1does not exist in region. make sure that colfamily has a valid name. check your table families with "describe" from the shell

Comment: As the "description" of the table is little long, I have added that as a separate answer, Kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

For my case make sure all region on line:
check you region count and you region data file count in hdfs. 
If they are different, you need try to fix hbase metadata.